# How to express arrays using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

There are two kind of codes - using array and pointers - that I made in order to get the same results.

My understanding of an array is that an array, even though we study 2-dimensions and 3 dimensions, within a computer, they are actually in a single line.

For example, char *p[3][2] would actually be in a straight line of 6 rooms, though we would study it as it having 3 row and 2 columns.

Therefore, the following two codes(**code A** and **code B**) would have the exact same result.

**Code A**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* p[3][2] = { "cat", "play", "hi", "rabbit", "babylon", "dog" };
    printf("%c\n", *(*(*p + 0) + 1));
    printf("%c\n", *(*(*p + 5) + 2));
    printf("%s\n", *(*p + 4));
    printf("%s\n", *(*p + 1) + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

**Code B**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* p[3][2] = { "cat", "play", "hi", "rabbit", "babylon", "dog" };
    printf("%c\n", *(*(*p + 0) + 1));
    printf("%c\n", *(*(*(p + 2) + 1) + 2));
    printf("%s\n", *(*(p + 2)));
    printf("%s\n", *(*(p + 0) + 1) + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Would my understanding be correct?

---

I edited the code due to some mistakes being made.

The result would be that both codes would print

```
a
g
babylon
lay
```

Comment: @user3121023 So potential U.B. ?

Comment: No, this actually is an array of arrays (of pointers to `char`.  Not everything accessible using `arr[1][2]` works that way, but in this case it does: nowhere in memory is there a pointer to `p[1]`.

Comment: The 2nd snippet does not compile. Please double check.

Comment: I edited the code due to some mistakes while copying and pasting the code. It should run properly this time with the proper results.